# List View loading same data twice when scrolling for first time after that working fine

Tags: java, android

View Complaint Activity:

In this i have done debugging but i was unable to know the reason why the data is coming twice after scrolling. I have even check the data coming from server through postman but the data is not coming duplicate its coming perfectly fine the problem seems to be in front end while we are putting the data through adapter inside activity on scrolling.

```
public class ViewComplaintActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, View.OnClickListener {

   TextView tv_notData;
   List<Ticket> _data = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
   ComplaintsAdapter settlementAdapter;
   private String TAG = "ViewComplaintActivity";
   private int visibleThreshold = 5;
   private int currentPage = 0;
   private int previousTotal = 0;
   private boolean loading = true;
   private boolean userScrolled = false;
```

a) Its is a Complaints Activity where we are showing the data comimg from server through adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_compliants);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    try {
        settlementAdapter = new ComplaintsAdapter(ViewComplaintActivity.this, _data);
        AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(settlementAdapter);
        animationAdapter.setAbsListView(ll_complaint_list);
        ll_complaint_list.setAdapter(animationAdapter);

        getComplaints(Utility.getTerminalId(ViewComplaintActivity.this), 0);

        ll_complaint_list.setOnScrollListener(this);
        fab_raise_complaint.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab_call_customer.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBackButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

private void getComplaints(String terminalid, int pagenumber) {
    if (!NetworkConnection.isConnected(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("subIdentifier", terminalid);
    jsonObject.addProperty("pageLimit", "10");
    jsonObject.addProperty("lastPageIndex", "" + pagenumber);

    IRetrofit iRetrofit = MoApplication.getInstance().getRetrofitOsTickets(this).create(IRetrofit.class);

    Log.e(TAG,"jsonObject "+jsonObject);

    iRetrofit.getAllTicket(jsonObject, new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            try {
                if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                    String resultFromJson = bufferedReader.readLine();
                   /* Log.e(TAG, "resultFromJson " + resultFromJson);*/

                    GetTicketsResponse getSettlementsResDTO = new Gson().fromJson(resultFromJson, GetTicketsResponse.class);

                    switch (getSettlementsResDTO.getResCode()) {
                        case "0001":
                            if (null != getSettlementsResDTO.getTickets()) {

                              _data.addAll(getSettlementsResDTO.getTickets());

                                settlementAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                if (_data.isEmpty()) {
                                    tv_notData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else {
                                    tv_notData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                            } else {
                                Utility.showToast(ViewComplaintActivity.this, "No data found.");
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Utility.showToast(ViewComplaintActivity.this, "Please try later.");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + e.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            if (Utility.parseException(error)){
                Utility.mPosLogoutService((AppCompatActivity) ViewComplaintActivity.this);
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        /*Log.e(TAG,"one");*/
        Log.e(TAG,"scrollState "+scrollState);
        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
            userScrolled = true;
            fab_call_customer.hide();
            fab_raise_complaint.hide();
        } else {
            fab_call_customer.show();
            fab_raise_complaint.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        /*Log.e(TAG,"two");*/


        view.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if (userScrolled) {
            Log.e(TAG,"loading "+loading);

            if (loading) {
                Log.e(TAG,"totalItemCount "+totalItemCount);
                Log.e(TAG,"previousTotal "+previousTotal);
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false;
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    currentPage++;
                }
            }

            Log.e(TAG,"loadin after scroll "+loading);

            if (!loading && ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))) {
                getComplaints(Utility.getTerminalId(ViewComplaintActivity.this), currentPage);
                loading = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG,"user is idle");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (NetworkConnection.isConnected(this)) {
            if (v == fab_raise_complaint) {
                Utility.navigate(this, RaiseComplaintActivity.class);
            } else if (v == fab_call_customer) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(Constant.helplineNumber.trim())));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } else if (v == ivBackButton) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewComplaintActivity.this, HomeQrActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public class ComplaintsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static String TAG = "ComplaintsAdapter";
    List<Ticket> _data;
    Context _c;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ComplaintsAdapter(Context context, List<Ticket> getData) {
        _data = getData;
        _c = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e(TAG,"_data.size()"+_data.size());
        return _data.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.e(TAG,"_data.get(position)"+_data.get(position));
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        /*Log.e(TAG,"getData"+_data.toString());*/
        try {
            if (view == null) {
                /*Log.e(TAG,"getData1"+_data.toString());*/
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) 
                _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = li.inflate(R.layout.row_item_view_complaints, 
                null);
            } else {
                /*Log.e(TAG,"getData2"+_data.toString());*/
                view = convertView;
            }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv_ticketNo = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticketNo);
            holder.tv_submitDate = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.tv_submitDate); //ticket comments
            holder.tv_updatedDate = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.tv_updatedDate);//will act as ticket 
            last modified time
            holder.tv_ticketStatus = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticketStatus); //ticket status open 
            or close
            holder.tv_comment = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.tv_comment);
            holder.tv_subject = (TextView) 
           view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);

            final Ticket ticket = _data.get(position);
            holder.tv_ticketNo.setText("#" + ticket.getTicketNo());
            holder.tv_submitDate.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Created On: 
            </b>" + Utility.dateReformatting("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd 
            MMM yyyy", ticket.getCreated())));
            holder.tv_updatedDate.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Modified On: 
            </b>" + Utility.dateReformatting("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd 
            MMM yyyy", ticket.getModified())));
            holder.tv_ticketStatus.setText(ticket.getStatus());
            holder.tv_subject.setText(null != ticket.getSubject() && !ticket.getSubject().isEmpty() ? ticket.getSubject().trim().replace("|", "") : "NA"); //comments
            if (null != ticket.getComment() && !ticket.getComment().isEmpty()) {

            holder.tv_comment.setText(Html.fromHtml(ticket.getComment()));
                holder.tv_comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.tv_comment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
                //holder.tv_comment.setText(null != ticket.getComment() && !ticket.getComment().isEmpty() ? ticket.getComment() : ""); //comments
            if (ticket.getStatus().startsWith("Open"))
              holder.tv_ticketStatus.setTextColor(_c.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_success));
            else
                Log.e(TAG,"getData4"+_data.toString());
             holder.tv_ticketStatus.setTextColor(_c.getResources().getColor(R.color_color));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void set_data(List<Ticket> _data) {
        this._data = _data;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_ticketStatus, tv_ticketNo, tv_submitDate, 
        tv_updatedDate, tv_comment, tv_subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a log inside getComplaints() and see if it is getting called twice for the initial time. I am afraid if that is the case then `if (!loading && ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))) {
                getComplaints(Utility.getTerminalId(ViewComplaintActivity.this), currentPage);
                loading = true;
            }` is failing.

Comment: okk I am going to try that.

Comment: not able to recognize why its not working.agin same data of top 10 list loaded twice.